# Electric field lines definition question

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

I have a question about the definition of electric field lines. Do they refer to $\mathbf E$ or
$\mathbf D$, where $\mathbf D = ε_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P$ ?

So when I'm plotting an electric field's lines (e.g. in a program), should I plot them using $\mathbf E$ or $\mathbf D$ as input?

Comment: You can plot whatever you want to.  It depends on the problem which one is relevant.

Comment: @nasu If I want to check the dependence of field lines on $ε$, within a material with $ε$ permittivity and conditions such that $\mathbf E$ is independent of $ε$, would be a better choice to plot field lines of $\mathbf D$?

Comment: The dependence of which field lines?

Comment: Electric field lines. When we are referring to them (e.g in bibliography) do they usually correspond to E or D?

Comment: E is the electric field.  D is the displacement field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric field line refers to the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ but people didn't want to bother themselves with bound charge field and free charge field. So it's convenient to use $\mathbf{D}$ so-called electric displacement so that all we need to care about is free
charge density that is in our control.
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D}=\rho_f$$
or in integral form
$$\oint \mathbf{D}\cdot d\mathbf{a}=Q_{f_{enc}}$$

where $Q_{f_{enc}}$ denotes the total free charge enclosed in the volume. This is a particularly
a useful way to express Gauss’s law, in the context of dielectrics, because
it makes reference only to free charges, and the free charge is the stuff we control.
The bound charge comes along for the ride: when we put the free charge in place,
a certain polarization automatically ensues, and
this polarization produces the bound charge. In a typical problem, therefore, we
know $ρ_f$, but we do not (initially) know $ρ_b$; In particular, whenever the requisite symmetry is present,
we can immediately calculate D by the standard Gauss’s law methods.